# User re-posts downvoted question, then deleted old one. How to handle?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, deleted-questions, reopen-closed

Consider this scenario:

1. A user post question **X**.
2. Question **X** gets downvoted.
3. The OP re-posts question **X** as question **Y**, a literal copy-paste.
4. I hammer question **Y** as duplicate of **X**.
5. Question **Y** (inexplicably) gets 2 upvotes while closed.
6. OP deletes question **X**, and contacts me on chat to re-open **Y**.

Now, I'm reluctant to re-open the newer question, as this whole scenario smells like "downvote evasion" to me.

Since the user contacted me on chat, I've asked the user to undelete the older question, **X**, and to remove the new one.

Was that the right course of action?

If the user doesn't act on the request to remove the duplicate, what, if anything, should I do?

Comment: Note: I've left out the relevant links for now. We don't necessarily want the meta effect to kick in.

Comment: Question Y actually has 3 upvotes, and 1 down

Comment: The XY problem, from a different angle.

Comment: This can't be the correct course of events; you can't delete a question when other questions are closed as duplicates of it, even if you're self-deleting as OP.

Comment: Dupe closure: `2017-05-03 08:34:32Z` Deleted: `2017-05-03 08:37:27Z`. Grace period, possibly, @TylerH?

Comment: @Cerbrus Ugh, must be. I hate that thing; it does nothing but allow people to circumvent the rules for... no good reason. I had no idea the grace period applied to actions other than posting an answer.

Comment: Flag for moderation stating that they keep reposting and deleting (and vice-versa); that should put a damper on things and hopefully sets them straight.

Comment: _"keep reposting and deleting"_ is a bit of an overstatement. It's just one case.

Comment: @Cerbrus believe me; I've seen this often. It's also the start of a behaviour pattern.

Comment: *"If the user doesn't act on the request to remove the duplicate, what, if anything, should I do?"* - Flag for moderation or ask again. If they still fail to respond, the former applies.

Comment: Now, do we need to file a bug report about the OP being able to delete the dupe target?

Comment: "Question Y (inexplicably) gets 2 upvotes while closed." - not so hard to find two friends with SO account who upvote you I guess ;>

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Users asking a post repeatedly is quite a normal scene. The users do that to either

1. Get more attention to their post (as they feel that no one else will see their post just because it's a few hours old), or
2. Get rid of the downvotes.

In the general sense:

- If there is a single case, then flag as dupe and go ahead. You may want to leave a comment to the [canonical post on getting attention for unanswered posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). If you want to be a bit more helpful, then hammer the worse of the two questions as the dupe instead of choosing the newer one.
- If the user does it a second time, flag it for mod attention. We'll delete the additional posts (or merge them in the rare cases where there's a really good answer) and send the user a warning.
- If the user does it again, after your flag has been marked helpful, then it's clear that the user is not aware of our system. Flag them again, we'll either send a stronger message or a suspension.

In this particular scenario:

What you have done is correct. As they were exact reposts and asked within 1hr of the original, hammering the new one is the perfect way.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, StackOverflow should employ/implement/deply/use a better, and **system-wide and automatic duplicate detection**.

If a user copy&pastes the exact same question, just redirect him to his original question, "we already found your question" (possibly: do you want to edit it, if they changed something slightly). Or allow them to "bounce" the question to get more attention (effectively just touching the timestamp, as an edit would do?), suggest to improve it or offer a reward.

On the implementation side, it may be enough to simply compare to the last 3 questions.

If the user copy and pastes to a different site, ask him if he wants to flag his earlier question for migration instead.

Would save everyone a lot of effort. Cross-posts and duplicates are a waste of time.

Comment: You're assuming the posting of an exact duplicate will be an accident. I think your assumption is wrong, and if it is wrong, then your suggestion is very much unhelpful: the duplicate will just end up modified to the point where the system no longer detects it as a duplicate, and it makes it harder for other users to clean up the mess. (Note that according to the comments, in this case it wasn't an exact duplicate, and in this case it may have been well-intended.)

Comment: That is why I suggest to direct the users to the edit function, and force them to edit their old question rather than cloning. You can design the UI this way, rather than just displaying a "you cannot post this", and that way encourage them to randomize. Similarly, allowing them to bump a question to get more attention will, for many, replace the "need" to ask again. And most users who post duplicates / cross-post are new users. As long as it is easier to follow the suggestions ("do you want to edit your question instead?) they will likely do this rather than trying to bypass the rule.