# What we do when a user deletes their question and asks the same question again

Tags: discussion, questions

As I was visiting the [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) questions, I found this question:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151433/write-text-vertically-in-txt-file*

Some users downvoted it, and it was deleted. After a few minutes, the OP asked the same question again:

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151523/write-vertically-into-text-file*

That question was closed.

My questions are:

1. On Stack Overflow, is there a method to prevent this type of behavior or not?
2. Should we cast close votes again for that? I ask because close votes are limited, and I used two of my votes here.

Comment: The closest thing we have to a way of preventing this behaviour is to block users from being able to ask any question at all if they ask too many questions that get closed.

Comment: By repeating their mistakes, users generally dig themselves in a hole. If posts keep getting badly received, OP ends up getting banned or rate limited as far as posting questions is concerned.

Comment: @SurajRao Maybe, but it still happens, and I have seen that a question had a negative score, the OP deleted it and posted the same question again, and it got a positive score. I believe it was discussed here on meta too.

Comment: I don't understand the user why upvoted. as per contains its too low

Comment: @SurajRao That happens when a user never, or basically never, asks an appropriate question.  When people are asking a mix of good and bad questions, enough to not get question banned, that mechanism ceases to stop this type of abuse.

Comment: @Servy agreed on that. There could be cases like that though I haven't come across it

Comment: @SurajRao I see it all the time.  It honestly takes quite a lot to get question banned.  Lots of people delete and re-post posts that aren't particularly close to being question banned.  I personally notice it probably around once every week or two (And twice in the last two days, in fact), and it's not an easy thing to notice, so it happens quite a lot without anyone realizing.

Comment: related: [Aren't new users throttled asking questions anymore?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601) "If your first question is downvoted and you try to ask another one 40 minutes later, you'll be forced to wait at least a day..."

Comment: It might be worth flagging for moderator intervention.

Comment: You don't need to do anthing :-)

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson its a community site and we are responsible to run it better as we can

Comment: @mega6382: I have seen the same behaviour in some tags, where a reposted question fares better than the original. I suspect it’s because a question is more likely to attract downvotes if it’s already been downvoted (resp. closevoted) or attracted negative comments—sadly, sometimes from people who simply misunderstand the question!

Answer (score 16):

> In Stack Overflow, is there a method to prevent this type of behaviour or not?

Yes. It's called a [Question Ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). That user didn't escape the downvotes by deleting his question. In fact, he dug himself a deeper hole by re-asking the question (which is a [policy violation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270193/reasking-a-question)) and giving the same users another chance to downvote his question. Once his overall score sinks low enough, he won't be able to ask anything for months or years.

> Should we cast closing vote again for that because closing votes are limited and for same question, 2 of my votes are used.

Yes. Even if you don't mod flag it, closure is the appropriate course of action. If it was close-worthy before, it's close-worthy the second time. Same goes for downvotes.

Comment: The question ban is a very poor means of preventing this, as it only prevents it for a very small percentage of the people that actually engage in this behavior.  This example is a great example of it.  The user in question, just looking at their profile, is quite far from a question ban.  They could keep engaging in this behavior for quite some time without a question ban inhibiting them.

Comment: @Servy What makes you say that? They currently have only one question that's not deleted sitting at -2. Sure, they have plenty of answers, but I'm not sure answers have any impact on question bans.

Comment: @Rob Answers count for less (how much less no one knows exactly), but they do count, so no, they're nowhere near being question banned.

Comment: If a user repeatedly asks the same question, do [flag for moderator attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348736/user-re-posts-downvoted-question-then-deleted-old-one-how-to-handle). Moderators will send them a warning/suspension message.

Comment: @Machavity curious to know. Would reposting the same question but with less code than the first one be considered as spamming?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner If it's still the same user and essentially the same question, I'd mod flag it.

Comment: @Machavity ok thanks. I voted to close too soon for it and I'd of hammered it had I looked at their past questions first.

Answer (score -31):

Sometimes you have to stop and think about the person asking the question. In most cases they are trying to solve a legitimate question in their eyes. That may not be apparent to an expert in the field. There are thousands of novice programmers that need a little extra help to solve what appears to be a simple or not possible problem. Please take this into consideration when jumping to ban someone from asking questions.

**EDIT:** I see from the number of downvotes I just received that my comments are pointless.

Comment: I don't think ignoring or easing up on our rules solves any problem. We're not expecting experts, we're expecting people who bother to respect our time (by doing extensive research beforehand) and read and try their best to follow the rules.

Comment: @Dukeling At least for me, actually knowing *what* to research took plenty of experience. I think a lot of people on this site have forgotten what it is like to begin programming for the first time.

Comment: @LiamMcInroy I sympathise with how helpless some new users must feel, I really do, but I don't believe easing up on rules will do anything other than significantly reducing the quality of questions and making experts want to leave. There are plenty of places with less strict rules where these users can go. I think a potential good solution is to change how SO presents itself officially and what new users are shown.

Comment: This argument could be made (though I'd still disagree...) if we were talking about bans for single bad questions (or downvoting, or closing, or everything else that "hurts" new users). But why should we do *anything* for someone blatantly cheating the system by deleting and re-asking? Being new doesn't excuse you from obeying basic rules of the site.

Comment: You need to distinguish: There are basically no bad problems. There are problems which are off-topic of course. But appart the main thing is that the questions about the problems are often bad. If users follow the rules, share their research, clearly state at which point they need help (essentially stick to [ask]) their question is not bad - it will mostly just end up as duplicate (which is not bad at all). The problem is that most often, people do not stick to those rules. And this is indeed not a matter of being novice. (Also experts ask bad questions.)