# Should this be flagged for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, flags

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954554/how-to-be-a-man-like-piu) was posted 15 minutes after this substantially broader [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54954497/how-to-be-man-like-dev1) was posted and immediately massively downvoted (it's basically a "please write my entire thesis" question). The correct(?) behaviour obviously was for [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9518927/charith-banneheka) to edit their question or perhaps delete the first (it had no answers) and start again, but in this case they have created a [new account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11138628/charith-banneheka) from which to post the new question and I was wondering if this was deserving of or needing a moderator flag?

Note this topic has been raised before [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358975/what-we-do-when-a-user-deletes-their-question-and-asks-the-same-question-again), but in that case it was from the same user account, not a newly created one.

**Update**

I notice in the time I spent writing the question the new account has been deleted.

Comment: Yeah, that “be a man like DEV1” is some kind of weird spam that’s been posted the past hour or so. I’ve nuked two of them already by different users. Please flag.

Comment: My genuine curiosity here: why ask this question instead of flagging and seeing the reaction? Mods may still disagree with the flag even if meta says you should do it. Isn't the best way to answer that question to try and flag? (For what it's worth, it does make the user bypass certain limits, like the ban, so it's not a legit use of a secondary account, IMHO. So yes to the flag, if my vote counts :p)

Comment: @Patrice the reason I didn't just flag and see what happened is that you either get a "helpful" or "declined" message and there usually isn't enough information to help understand whether it was the right thing to do or not.

Comment: Care to post a screenshot for non-10k users?

Comment: @jhpratt Not so easy; it doesn't fit on my "screen". [Here's a mosaic of one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMTwE.png).

Comment: @CodyGray if you are on Chrome: Open the Developer Console, Ctrl+Shift P and then type 'capture full size screenshot'  ... click it ... be amazed ...